# How to add label if the PR's code contains specific text?

Tags: github

We are using [Labeler](https://github.com/actions/labeler) to have labels on the Pull Request depending on which file we are modifying.
I'm searching for a similar tool, that should check the modified code lines for a specific text. Is there any tool like this available?

So for instance, if I want to check for "@deprecated" in the modified lines, it would add a specific label to the PR.

Comment: I don't think I have seen a tool to do this but you could create a workflow to do this pretty easily.